# Solana Web3 Instructions Suddenly Not Working (Next.JS)

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, nextjs

I've got a Next.js application making a few transactions calls using `'@solana/wallet-adapter-react'` and `@solana/spl-token`

The application has been working fine locally until with the transactions working as expected and creating new tokens, (I have other calls not included for revoking authority etc that were working as well)

With zero changes made to the code I'm now encountering all these tx's failing. The transaction in Phantom that usually shows `+X tokens` and `- X sol` to create a token now shows `No assets changing` and the instructions seem like they're missing data.

Below is the `createToken` call and an example of what Phantom looks like for a tx that won't be sent.

```
                SystemProgram.transfer({
                    fromPubkey: publicKey,
                    toPubkey: creationFeeRecipientPublicKey, // account 1
                    lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 0.069,
                }),
                SystemProgram.createAccount({
                    fromPubkey: publicKey,
                    newAccountPubkey: mintKeypair.publicKey,
                    space: MINT_SIZE,
                    lamports: lamports,
                    programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                }),
                createInitializeMintInstruction(
                    mintKeypair.publicKey,
                    Number('9'),
                    publicKey,
                    publicKey,
                    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
                ),
                createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(publicKey, tokenATA, publicKey, mintKeypair.publicKey),
                createMintToInstruction(
                    mintKeypair.publicKey,
                    tokenATA,
                    publicKey,
                    Number(supply) * Math.pow(10, Number('9'))
                ),
                createMetadataInstruction
            );
```

[image: phantom tx details]

[image: phantom tx]

Comment: Did you make sure you have enough sol in that wallet?

Comment: Whoops, you're right! Seems I didn't realise I'd moved too much sol out of the wallet. Right now it just fails... is there some way for me to let the user know if they have insufficient balance for a transaction as the error messaging isn't super clear?

Comment: Yes. A better UX would be adding a balance check of the 'source' wallet in your UI before sending a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is failing because there is not enough sol in the wallet to pay for the fees and the new account.

To solve this you can use

```
 let balance = await connection.getBalance(feePayer.publicKey);
  console.log(`${balance / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL} SOL`);
```

And show a warning popup to the user in case he does not have enough sol.